# Python does not show result of print statements in class

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is probably trivial, but I got not resolution when searching for this:

I have the following simple class:

```
class Celcius:
    def __init__(self, temperature=0):
        self.temperature = temperature

    def to_fahrenheit(self):
        return (self.temperature*1.8) + 32

    def get_temperature(self):
        print "getting temp"
        return self._temperature

    def set_temperature(self, value):
        if value < -273:
            raise ValueError("dayum u trippin' fool")
        print "setting temp"
        self._temperature = value

    temperature = property(get_temperature, set_temperature)

c = Celcius()
```

When I run this in Sublime Text 3 (by hitting cmd+B) the console does not print anything. I should see:

```
setting temp
```

If I add the following to the end of the script:

```
print "banana"
print "apple"
```

both lines are printed as expected.

If I run the above python script from the terminal (with python -u, or just python), the result is exactly the same. I assume I am missing something very stupid. Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This does not work because you wrote

```
class Celcius:
    ...
```

while using features of new-style classes. To use properties, you need to inherit from object:

```
class Celcius(object):
    ...
```

does the trick.

Reference: [Descriptor Howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#definition-and-introduction), quote: *Note that descriptors are only invoked for new style objects or classes (a class is new style if it inherits from object or type)*

Comment: Ah, that worked! Thank you. So I should always inherent from `object` just to be safe?

Comment: @luffe: Read about ["new-style class"](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) in the glossary. In Python 3 you always have new-style classes, so your code will run there without modifications.

Answer (score -1):

You are not calling the `set_temperature(self, value)` method at all.

This line

```
self.temperature = temperature
```

in your `__init__()` method (which is called by the `c = Celcius()`) just sets the `self.temperature` directly, without calling the setter.

The obvious solution is to rewrite your **init**() method from:

```
def __init__(self, temperature=0):
    self.temperature = temperature
```

to:

```
def __init__(self, temperature=0):
    self.set_temperature(temperature)
```

Comment: But if I run the above code (with parenthesis around the print statement) on www.repl.it's Python 3 interpreter, it prints "setting temp"...?

Comment: There is a `temperature` *property*, it calls `set_temperature` when assigning to it.

Comment: You are right, I know about properties but I missed that line. Thank you.

Comment: @luffe: In Python 3 it will use the property because the so called "new style classes" are default there. In Python 2 you have to make `object` the base class.